# `scp` searches for target alias on source host instead of local machine

Tags: scp

When I try to copy files between two hosts, of which the second is identified by an alias:

```
scp host:foo alias:
```

`scp` tries to resolve `alias` by looking into `host:.ssh/config` and not my local `~/.ssh/config` -- in other words, as if I've ssh-ed to `host` and then executed `scp foo alias:`.

Of course, this fails if I do not have the alias `alias` defined on `host`. Is this the intended behavior?

Running Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Indeed, the `scp host1:foo host2:` is the same as doing the `scp foo host2:` on the `host1` (The `scp`, more or less, first connects to the `host1` and executes the `scp foo host2:` there).

If you want to transfer files via a local host (what I believe would also mean the alias is resolved locally), add the `-3` switch:

> `-3`: Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the
>   local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between
>   the two remote hosts.

https://man.openbsd.org/scp

Comment: Oh God. `scp` has options `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, `-4` and `-6` with three different "groups" of meanings. *Shudder* Anyway, thanks, that's it.